# AngularDart - upload to shared hosting server

Tags: server, dart, angular-dart

so I have my AngularDart app up and running on my machine (I used stagehand). Now is the time where I want to upload it to a shared hosting server. My question is: what is the correct procedure to do that? Because obviously Dart doesn't run natively and the compiled js files are required. (I already have access to the file manager of my server).

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pub-build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `build` command of the `pub` tool.

https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pub-build

> Use `pub build` when you’re ready to deploy your web app. When you run
>   pub build, it generates the assets for the current package and all of
>   its dependencies, putting them into new directory named build.

Comment: Thank you :) Didn't know about that, yet!

Answer (score 1):

I just run this on my folder

```
pub run build_runner build -o build -r
```

It build my app and creates a output `build` folder for `release`. Then I ftp'd it to my webhosting. And because the webhost supports nodejs and javascript, i just open my web browser and voila!